# table-striped bootstrap class not working but other classes are working

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, bootstrap-4

I have created a table using bootstrap class in a angular project. Only table-striped and table-hover class is not working remaining classes like table-primary is working. and I have not written a single line of css code (no issue of overriding).I have tried other examples in stack but didn't work the issues were of tbody. i have tried including tbody tag but didn't work.

```html
<div class="container box" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <table class="table table-striped table-fit table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <th>Item</th> 
                            <th>Amount</th> 
                            <th>Category</th> 
                            <th>Location</th> 
                            <th>Spent On</th> 
                        </tr> 
                        
                            <tr *ngFor="let entry of expenseEntries">
                                <th scope="row">{{ entry.item }}</th>
                                <th>{{ entry.amount }}</th> 
                                <td>{{ entry.category }}</td> 
                                <td>{{ entry.location }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.spendOn | date: 'short' }}</td>
                            </tr>
                      
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags inside the `<table>` tag.

table content inside the tbody will only be affected by `.table-striped` class as mentioned in the official [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#striped-rows)

Comment: Thank you my mistake was that i  put <tbody>  tag inside <thead> tag initially then i tried removing <tbody> tag. but i now wrapped correctly outside <thead> tag

Answer (score 0):

at the beginning I wrapped  and   wrongly.
my mistake was that i put  tag inside  tag initially then i tried removing  tag. but i now wrapped correctly outside 
like this

```html
 <div class="container box" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <table class="table table-striped table-fit table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <th>Item</th> 
                            <th>Amount</th> 
                            <th>Category</th> 
                            <th>Location</th> 
                            <th>Spent On</th> 
                        </tr> 
                    
                    <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let entry of expenseEntries">
                                <th scope="row">{{ entry.item }}</th>
                                <th>{{ entry.amount }}</th> 
                                <td>{{ entry.category }}</td> 
                                <td>{{ entry.location }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.spendOn | date:'fullDate' | uppercase }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>  
                    </thead>  
                </table>
            </div>
```

but actually  tag should be after closing  tag like the below one code

```html
<div class="container box" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <table class="table table-striped table-fit table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <th>Item</th> 
                            <th>Amount</th> 
                            <th>Category</th> 
                            <th>Location</th> 
                            <th>Spent On</th> 
                        </tr> 
                    </thead>  
                    <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let entry of expenseEntries">
                                <th scope="row">{{ entry.item }}</th>
                                <th>{{ entry.amount }}</th> 
                                <td>{{ entry.category }}</td> 
                                <td>{{ entry.location }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.spendOn | date:'fullDate' | uppercase }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>  
                    
                </table>
            </div>
```